# How to Block Camera switching in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use font camera by default and want to disable the switch option to the back camera.
How can i do it???

````
            var i = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            i.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
            i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
            startActivityForResult(i,101)
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the camera APIs directly or using a library (CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit/Android, etc.).

Your current code is launching the user's choice of camera app, and you have no means of forcing that camera app to disable certain cameras.

Also, please note that not every Android device has a front-facing camera. If that is a requirement of your app, put the appropriate `<uses-feature>` element in your manifest.